# Android Bitmap to List View

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a bitmap from a url to my list i pass my bitmap as an object but my image wont display

```
for(int i=0;i<CarsArray.length();i++){
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    JSONObject e = CarsArray.getJSONObject(i);

    map.put("InventoryID",  String.valueOf(i));
    map.put("Year", " " +  e.getString("Year") + " " + e.getString("Make") + " " + e.getString("Model"));
    map.put("Stock Number", "Stock#: " + e.getString("StockNumber"));
    map.put("VIN", "VIN: " + e.getString("VIN"));
    map.put("Color", "Exterior Color: " + e.getString("ExteriorColor"));
    map.put("InColor", "Interior Color: " + e.getString("InteriorColor"));
    map.put("Mileage", "Odometer: " + e.getString("Mileage"));
    map.put("Price", "$" + e.getString("Price") + "0");
    map.put("VehicleStatus", e.getString("VehicleStatus"));
    map.put("InsertedDate", e.getString("InsertedDate"));
    bimage =  getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
    map.put("Image", bimage);
    mylist.add(map);

}
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.parsejson,
        new String[] { "Year", "Stock Number", "VIN", "Color", "Mileage", "Price", "VehicleStatus", "InColor", "InsertedDate", "Image"},
        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_subtitle2, R.id.item_subtitle3 , R.id.item_subtitle4,
                R.id.item_subtitle5, R.id.item_subtitle6, R.id.item_subtitle8,  R.id.item_subtitle9, R.id.imageView1});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: is the rest of the data apart from image being displayed in the listview?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom adapter and override getView() method. Inside that method use these lines of code to show image:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setImageBitmap(mylist.get("Image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your the following line of code

```
bimage =  getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
map.put("Image", bimage);
```

with

```
bimage =  getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
 map.put("Image", d);
```